# MVC BeginForm With Fading Circle Animation activated even there are Data Annotation Errors

Tags: javascript, vb.net, model-view-controller, html.beginform

I have this Razor code.

```
    @Using Html.BeginForm("SaveBranch", "Branch", Model, FormMethod.Post, New With {.id = "myForm", .class = "form-horizontal", .role = "form", .onsubmit = "DisplayProgressMessage('#btnSave', 'Saving...');"})
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @<text>
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <fieldset>
                <div class="col-md-6">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="row">
                            @Html.LabelFor(Function(m) m.BranchName, New With {.class = "col-md-2 control-label"})
                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                @Html.HiddenFor(Function(m) m.BranchID)
                                @Html.TextBoxFor(Function(m) m.BranchName, New With {.class = "form-control", .maxlength = 50})
                                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(Function(m) m.BranchName, "", New With {.class = "text-danger"})
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
<div class="row">
                        <button type="submit" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary pull-left"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-save" style="margin-right: 4px;"></i> Save!</button>
                        <a href="@Url.Action("SearchMedexBranch", New With {.Server = Model.Server})" , class="btn btn-success pull-left" id="btnSearch"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></i> Back To Search</a>
                            <hr>
                        </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>      
        </text> 
    End Using

<script>
    function DisplayProgressMessage(ctl, msg) {
        // Check if there are Data Annotation errors before starting the animation
        if (document.querySelectorAll(".field-validation-error").length > 0) {
            console.log("Field Error count :", document.querySelectorAll(".field-validation-error"));
            return false; // Prevent form submission when there are errors
        }
        $(ctl).prop("disabled", true).text(msg);
        $(".alert").removeClass("hidden");
        $("body").loadingModal({
            position: "auto",
            text: "Processing...",
            color: "#fff",
            opacity: "0.7",
            backgroundColor: "rgb(0,0,0)",
            animation: "fadingCircle"
        });
        console.log("Returning True...");
        return true;
    }

    // Add event listener to the form submission
    document.getElementById("myForm").addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        // Call the DisplayProgressMessage function before submitting the form
        const formIsValid = DisplayProgressMessage(document.querySelector("button[type=submit]"), "Processing...");

        // If the function returns false, prevent the form submission
        if (!formIsValid) {
            // Re-enable the submit button and hide loading animation
            document.querySelector("button[type=submit]").removeAttribute("disabled");
            $(".alert").addClass("hidden");
            $("body").loadingModal("hide");
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    });
</script>
```

It calls a Fading Circle Animation while the Form saves in the controller.
It works **fine** provided there are no Data Annotation errors.

If there are Data Annotation errors like empty fields, the **POST** is not called *(w/c is good)* but the Fading Circle Animation is called thereby making changes to the field impossible since the java script also disables the field and the Save button.

[image]

As you can see in the picture above, there is a Data Annotation Error "Please provide a Branch Code!" I do not want the fading circle to be invoked.
I cannot proceed to edit the field if they are disabled.
I only want the Fading Circle to appear if there are no errors.

I hope you can help me. :)